# Does stroke aesthetic work with shapes 0 - 14?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Started learning R recently using a GitHub open book. In question 5 under [Exercise 3.3.1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#exercises-1) of the open book, the question asked: "What does the `stroke` aesthetic do? What shapes does it work with? (Hint: use `?geom_point`)"

I understand that the `stroke` aesthetic works with shapes 21-24 since they have borders but I'm wondering why do the [unofficial answer](https://jrnold.github.io/r4ds-exercise-solutions/data-visualisation.html#exercise-3.3.5) not mention it works with shapes 0-14 when you can change the colour of those borders too? There's no official answer & many have deemed this book accurate in answering the original open book's exercises, hence the term "unofficial answer". It is also not mentioned in [cran.r-project.org](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/ggplot2-specs.html) too, under Shape's "Colour and fill" (nearing the end of the page).

Loaded tidyverse and the code I used for shape 5

```
ggplot(data = mpg)+
 geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), shape = 5, colour = "green", stroke = 3)
```

& the code I used for shape 23

```
ggplot(data = mpg)+
 geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), shape = 23, colour = "green", stroke = 3)
```

both gave the [same plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWtoP.png) with no errors in RStudio. However, despite the same results, I am worried there may be future repercussions from this "mistake" that I am unaware of; hence the question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stroke` argument is used to control the size of the edge/border of your point. If we say it differently it changes the size of the border for shapes like in the unofficial answer.

If you lock closely to https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html. You will notice that shapes 21 - 24 have both `stroke` and `fill` argument because they are fill with texture.

It is not the case for 0 - 14 shapes. The `fill` arguments doesn't work for them. You can't change the inside color of the `shape`, it is always white, see below. However the `stroke` argument works because they have border and the `size` argument works as well, but the inside is always white whatever `fill` argument is given.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g1_bis <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             shape = 5,
             fill = "red",
             colour = "green",
             stroke = 3)


g2_bis <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             fill = "red",
             colour = "green",
             shape = 5,
             size = 10)

grid.arrange(g1_bis, g2_bis)
```

[image]

For the shapes from 14 - 21 the `size` and `stroke` arguments does almost the same I think.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             shape = 17,
             stroke = 3)

g2 <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             shape = 17,
             size = 3)

grid.arrange(g1, g2)
```

[image]

Your exemple is absolutly normal because you didn't precise any fill so the shape 23 is fill with white but the border is green and big enough : 3. The same for the shape 5. The `size` argument control the size of the filled area for all shapes.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             shape = 17,
             stroke = 3)

g2 <- ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy),
             shape = 17,
             size = 3)

grid.arrange(g1, g2)
```

[image]

Just to conclud the post with the ugliest plot I ever made. I discover lot of things on the subtility between border and fill. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I examined different line of code to see what FILL and STROKE does. at last I understood that u can decide about the filling color by using FILL but like shapes every color is defined by number. for example: 4 for blue and 3 for green. and STROKE is about the wideness of the borders of the shapes. the bigger value for STROKE the bolder borders.
I hope that I could have answer ur question.